# It works in production but InvalidStateException (unmanaged object) in Arquillian/Junit test

Tags: rest, jpa, openjpa, apache-tomee

There is a ManyToMany relationship between ClassA and ClassB. ClassA holds a collection of ClassB objects, while ClassB doesn't know anything about ClassA. The relevant part of Class A looks something like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="ClassA_ClassB_JoinTable",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="classAId"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="classBId"))
private ArrayList<ClassB> classBReferences = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
```

I've got a simple CrudDao and the relevant code from there is:

```
@Singleton
public class CrudDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myDatabaseName")
    private EntityManager em;

    public <E> E create(E e) {
        em.persist(e);
        return e;
    }
}
```

I've created a contrived/simplified example to illustrate the problem I'm having. I wrote a simplified REST endpoint that looks like this:

```
@Path("/simplified")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class SimplifiedService {

    @Inject
    private CrudDao crudDao;

    @GET
    @Path("")
    public Response watchItCrash() {

        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        classB.setAttribute("Blah!");
        crudDao.create(classB);

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.getClassBReferences().add(classB);
        crudDao.create(classA);

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

When I stand up my REST service (using TomEE) I can make a GET call and everything works perfectly. However, I'm also trying to use Arquillian and JUnit to test my REST endpoints, which is where I run into trouble.

My Arquillian/JUnit test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SimplifiedServiceIT {

    @ArquillianResource
    private URL webappUrl;

    @Deployment()
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addClasses(SimplifiedService.class, CrudDao.class)
                .addAsWebInfResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource("test-resources.xml", "resources.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetRoles() throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = webappUrl.toURI().resolve("simplified");
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
        Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();
        Response response = builder.get();
    }
}
```

Now obviously I'm not actually testing anything here, but I can see that the GET call is successfully made, ClassB is successfully persisted, but it fails to persist ClassA. This is the error I get when I try to persist ClassA:

```
WARNING: Unexpected exception from beforeCompletion; transaction will roll back

<openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Encountered unmanaged object "ClassB@56c6d515" in life cycle state  unmanaged while cascading persistence via field "ClassA.classBReferences<element:class ClassB>" during flush.  However, this field does not allow cascade persist. You cannot flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to unmanaged objects. Suggested actions:
a) Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "persist" or "all" (JPA orm.xml), 
b) enable cascade-persist globally, 
c) manually persist the related field value prior to flushing. 
d) if the reference belongs to another context, allow reference to it by setting StoreContext.setAllowReferenceToSiblingContext().
FailedObject: ClassB@56c6d515
```

Any idea why this works in 'production' but fails in the Arquillian/UnitTest environment?

Comment: Can you attach your Arquillian test's `@Deployment` method? Can you attach a simplified working test?

Comment: I'm going to see if I can make a further simplified test. The deployment looks something like this:

    @Deployment()
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addClasses(MyRestService.class, CrudDao.class)
                .addAsWebInfResource("META-INF/persistence.xml") 
                .addAsWebInfResource("test-resources.xml", "resources.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

Comment: @pirho I updated the original post to include a simplified example. I'm not sure if it can be simplified further.

Comment: Have you tried to add also `ClassA` & `ClassB` with `addClasses(..)`? Test seems good but maybe needs `webappUrl` resource also?

Comment: Just tried that, no luck. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not necessarily the reason but I think you need also `@(org.jboss.arquillian.transaction.api.annotation.)Transactional` before your test method.